# Android using a cursor on UI thread

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I am wondering when or if its ok to use a cursor to get data from a sqlite database on the ui thread. Basically I use a cursorloader to get a cursor. And then I want to do something with that cursor. Is it ok to do something with the cursor from the main ui thread? Really I just need to read one row from the cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrieving a row from a `Cursor` is not an expensive operation... querying the data from the database, on the other hand, could be time-consuming depending on the amount of data you are requesting and/or the complexity of the query. `CursorLoader`s query for `Cursor`s asynchronously so your approach is fine.

Comment: Just a heads up by the way. If your queries result in large amounts of data, (lots of columns and/or rows), the cursor window will not be able to fit your entire query result and whenever you try to move the cursor position outside the cursor window, a new file access occurs to repopulate the cursor window. This can easily happen when querying the MediaProvider with a large projection on a device with thousands of images/videos.

Answer (score -2):

It's OK. It's not a network operation.

EDIT: by "it's OK" I mean that Android 4.x won't force-close your app for doing that, like if would for performing network I/O on the main thread. Depending on the query time, it might or might not be appropriate to stall the UI thread. For a "get a single row from a single table by its primary key" kind of query, it's perfectly fine. For a hairy query that takes a second or more, consider a background thread and a progress dialog.

Comment: ok so anytime its not from a network then its ok? Why do you think someone put -1?

Comment: @user1486574 I put -1 because even queries to a local SQLite database should be performed asynchronously since you don't know how long they will take. Same goes for disk reads/writes. Network operations are definitely not the only way to abuse the UI thread.

Comment: What's next, spinning a thread for retrieving a preference? Hey, that's disk I/O, too! The real answer is that there's no single true answer. I can think of queries that are OK in the main thread and of ones that clearly are not. But at least the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is not to be worried about.

Comment: I agree that `SharedPreferences` are simple enough to retrieve and that they are OK to do on the UI Thread. But its better to write to `SharedPreferences` asynchronously. The Android SDK provides methods that do this as of API 9 (`Editor#commit`). You can also use Mark Murphy's (CommonsWare) `SharedPreferenceLoader` [**here**](http://bit.ly/OB291k). Like you said, "querying for a single row" is fine, but a lot of the times you don't want to risk it because stalling even for several hundredths of a second can lessen the user experience.

Comment: Displaying progress UI and spinning a thread is not free, either. Spinning a thread alone takes a few hundrethds of a second, thus further degrading the user experience. What's worse - a 50ms delay with stalled main thread or a 200ms delay with a nice "Please wait" window?

Comment: It's all about potentially stalling the main thread. You never know what other processes do with the filesystem when you try to make one little query to the DB. After developing apps since donut and eclair, I've seen that even the most innocent looking .query() or File operations cause an ANR in the end.